# how to get the time signature of my own songs

Tags: guitar, time-signatures

Lately I've been writing my own songs on guitar.i think most of them are in 4/4 time signature but i'm not pretty sure.
how can i figure out the time signature of my songs? 
is there any way to get the time signature?

Comment: I think you're doing it backwards.  First figure out what rhythm you want for your piece, then write the music.  My impression is that you don't have a lot of fundamental music theory background -- some reading materials may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a 'drum box' or the digital equivalent.  Set up a 4/4 rhythm.  Play your song to the beat and see if it fits!